# How to get the user with most comments from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get the user first name with the most comments. How can I do this?
Here are the tables.
The tables below are the setup for the database tables which I am trying to query.

```
CREATE TABLE User(
        userid varchar(3),
        firstname varchar(20),
        lastname varchar(20),
        age int, 
        PRIMARY KEY(userid)
    )ENGINE=INNODB;


    CREATE TABLE Comment(
        commentid varchar(3),
        userid varchar(3),
        eventid varchar(3),
        title varchar(20),
        comment varchar(50),
        PRIMARY KEY(commentid),
        FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES AnonymousUser(userid),
        FOREIGN KEY(eventid) REFERENCES Event(eventid)
    )ENGINE=INNODB;


    INSERT INTO User VALUES('U01','Charles','Darwin',99);
    INSERT INTO User VALUES('U02','Keisha','Strawn',24);
    INSERT INTO User VALUES('U03','Denise','Malcolm',59);
    INSERT INTO User VALUES('U04','Dennis','Stewart',19);
    INSERT INTO User VALUES('U05','Robert','Johns',45);
    INSERT INTO User VALUES('U06','Marsha','Stewart',33);

    INSERT INTO Comment VALUES ('C01','A01','E01','Boring Event','This event was boring');
    INSERT INTO Comment VALUES ('C02','A02','E01','Nice Nice Event','This event was Nice');
    INSERT INTO Comment VALUES ('C03','A03','E03','Wow','This event was Amazing');
    INSERT INTO Comment VALUES ('C04','A01','E01','Very Sad','I missed this event');
```

The query I tried is

```
SELECT User.userid FROM User 
JOIN comment ON comment.userid = user.userid 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(comment) 
FROM comment = (SELECT MAX(userid) FROM comment);
```

Comment: You might remove the reference(s) to the event table if it is not necessary to explain the problem. What query have you tried so far? What did it output? It looks like your data has *no* comments for any user, is that what you wanted?

Comment: SELECT User.userid
FROM User 
JOIN comment ON comment.userid = user.userid
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(comment) FROM comment = (SELECT MAX(userid) FROM comment);

Comment: You're getting the count after getting the max.  You need to do it the other way around.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    userid
FROM
    comment
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY count(userid) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Edit: oh, you need the username. Try this:

```
SELECT firstname 
FROM user 
WHERE userid = (
    SELECT 
        userid
    FROM
        comment
    GROUP BY userid
    ORDER BY count(userid) DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Query to get firstname with most comments is

```
select a.firstname, max(a.comment_count) from (
    select u.firstname, count(c.commentid) comment_count
    from user u join comment c on u.userid = c.userid
    group by u.firstname
)a;
```

That said, I noticed

1. One of the constraints on table 'comment' is pointing to a table 'AnonymousUser' **FOREIGN KEY(userid) REFERENCES AnonymousUser(userid)**. You have not shared the create table statement for that table.
   I had to remove this constraint from table definition in order to successfully create this table in my database

```
CREATE TABLE Comment(
  commentid varchar(3),
  userid varchar(3),
  eventid varchar(3),
  title varchar(20),
  comment varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(commentid)
);
```

2. You dataset for table 'comment' has no userid matching 'user.userid' values

I updated the 'comment' table inserts so I could get some result when executing my query.

```
INSERT INTO Comment VALUES ('C01','U01','E01','Boring Event','This event was boring');
INSERT INTO Comment VALUES ('C02','U01','E01','Nice Nice Event','This event was Nice');
INSERT INTO Comment VALUES ('C03','U03','E03','Wow','This event was Amazing');
INSERT INTO Comment VALUES ('C04','U06','E01','Very Sad','I missed this event');
```